# Does this character die in Resident Evil 7?

Tags: resident-evil-7

I finished the main storyline and he didn’t die or get infected to my recollection, but something I've learned recently is that

> Ethan Winters has been revived and is infected in RE8.

Comment: How is he revived if I didn’t see him dead in 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a flashback revealed in Resident Evil: Village it is explained that

> Ethan was killed by Jack when he stomps on Ethan's head in the prologue Unbeknownst to the both the player and Ethan you are infected by the E-Virus mold - likely from just being at the house or being force-fed mold-infected food shorty after getting stomped.

> Either way, the mold gives Ethan incredible regenerative abilities and allows him to survive dangers that would kill a normal human. You don't see Ethan die because from your perspective you were only knocked unconscious by the stomp - when you were actually, briefly, deceased.

> As you experienced, neither you (the player) or Ethan knew you became infected at this point - but it would explain the incredible encounters you are able to survive, such as losing your hand and having it stapled back on, or being able to use your arms to block any attack.

Answer (score -1):

This Character doesn't die on RE7, as Chris Redfield arrives with the rescue team, to rescue him.